# Module ImportError using PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, python-import, importerror

I have a pyspark job (spark 1.6.1, python 2.7). The basic structure is:

```
spark_jobs/
  __init__.py
  luigi_workflow.py
  my_pyspark/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    spark_job.py
    stuff/
      __init__.py
      module1.py
      module2.py
    analytics/
      __init__.py
      analytics.py
```

In my `spark_job.py` I have:

```
from dir1.module1 import func1
from dir1.module2 import func2
from analytics.analytics import some_analytics_func
...
func1(...)
func2(...)
some_analytics_func(...)
...
```

When I launch the spark job, `func1` and `func2` execute perfectly, but then I get:

`ImportError: No module named analytics.analytics`

This has been driving me absolutely insane. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I'm launching with a wrapper around `spark-submit` and designating the path with `python -m spark_jobs.my_pyspark`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where `dir1` is coming from? Shouldn't it be `from my_pyspark.stuff.module1 import func1`? Have you tried this before `from my_pyspark.analytics.analytics import some_analytics_func`? Since you are using Luigi, you can also try to build the package through [setup.py](https://docs.python.org/2/install/).

Hope this helps! I had this problems before but it can be solved.